# Problema con carga de datos en un TextView Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String emailuser;
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_tools,null);
mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
emailuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
TextView textemail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.texto_email2);
Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+emailuser,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
textemail.setText(emailuser);
```

Este es el código que estoy utilizando en un Fragment para poder recoger el email del usuario de la base de datos y lo que quiero hacer es mostrarlo en un TextView, el textView se encuentra en un fragment llamado fragment_tools.

El Toast lo estoy haciendo porque quería comprobar que me esta recogiendo bien los datos de la base de datos y efectivamente me los recoge porque me muestra el email del usuario que en mi caso es hola@hola.com

Comment: ¿En qué contexto está tu código? ¿Estás retornando la vista?

Comment: ¿Como que en que contexto? Te refieres al getContext del inflater?

Comment: Cuando hablo de *contexto*  me refiero a si el código que muestras se encuentra dentro de un método `onCreateView` o dónde. Pon el contexto completo del código, no veo que estés retornando la vista como sugiere [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es-419).

Comment: He subido la foto donde se encuentra todo el fragment, el fragment es uno creado ya por defecto cuando creas un navigation Drawer

Comment: En vez de la imagen es más útil poner el texto del código en todo su contexto. ¿Si cambias el  `return root;` por un `return view;` qué pasa? No entiendo por qué cargas dos vistas ahí ¿?

Comment: Madre mía, soy inutil, no había visto que tenía dos vistas. Ahora si que se me muestra, solo tenia que cambiar el return y ya esta, muchas gracias

Comment: No tenías vista para ver que tenías dos vistas :-) Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.  Simplemente no estabas retornando la vista que tenía el Fragment que mostraba el texto. Para otra ocasión generalmente se invita al usuario que te ha aclarado el problema a que de una respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: De verdad, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda. PD: gran sentido del humor :)

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String emailuser, nombreuser;

private ToolsViewModel toolsViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    toolsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ToolsViewModel.class);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_tools,null);
    mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    emailuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    TextView textemail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.texto_email2);
    textemail.setText(emailuser);

    nombreuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    TextView textnombre = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.texto_nombreusuario);
    textnombre.setText(nombreuser);
    return view;
}
```